# Django ignores transactions

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to use transaction in Django. It seems that django ignores it. If there is an exception in the block, I expect that the transaction will be rolled back and the DB won't be changed. However, the DB is changed when I query it later.

All my tables are InnoDB. Transactions in mysql-shell work perfectly.

python 2.7.5+, mysql 5.5.54, django 1.8.7.

This is my test code:

Django settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'my_app': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': ROOT_USER,
        'PASSWORD': ROOT_PASS,
        'HOST': ROOT_HOST,
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

code:

```
import django
import os

from django.db import transaction

from my_app.models import Account

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_proj.settings")
django.setup()

with transaction.atomic():
    Account.objects.create(account_name='newacc')
    raise Exception('no!!!!')
```

The expected result is that this object will not be in DB after execution.
The real result is that the account is created in DB, although there was an exception.

Even more than that: when debugging the code, when breaking at the 'raise' line, I can see the new object in DB already (using workbench).

Comment: How is this a test of transactions? Transaction is meant to ensure that a set of data modifications happen completely or not at all. We cannot tell how many modifications `Account.objects.create(account_name='newacc')` and you have not even described what the result of the above code was.

Comment: @Alasdair It is InnoDB, checked by:
SELECT  table_name, engine
FROM    information_schema.tables AS tb
WHERE   table_schema = 'my_schema';

Comment: I'm not an expert on python, nor on django, but I thought that the transactions module applied to database level operations, not on python level operations. The exception you raise is on python level and does not affect the database layer, hence there is no rollback.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks. However the fact that while debugging I already see the row in DB suggests that this block is not under transaction anyway.

Comment: @reformy or that the transaction has already been committed, or your isolation level is set to read uncommitted :) What about autocommit settings both on database and django levels?

Comment: I've found the problem. I changed the question because I thought it is harmless but that's the point. I am starting a transaction on the wrong DB.

Answer (score 3):

When using transaction.atomic(), one should use the parameter using='my_db_connection' to start the transaction on the relevant DB:

```
with transaction.atomic(using='my_db_connection'):
```

In your example:

```
with transaction.atomic(using='my_app'):
```

If this argument isn’t provided, Django uses the "default" database connection.